# Sending the same multiple emails instead of 1 email for loop bug

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have bug where when I run my send email function. its sending multiple emails instead of just one email notification here is my code what am I doing wrong??!?! I got 31 of the same emails. I believe the issue the for loop is sending an email each time the if statement is true instead of just one time if its true help.

here is my code:

```
function sendEmail(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //get active spreadsheet only! to get the url for the filter view
var SpreadsheetID = ss.getSheetId(); // get the sheet Id 
var spreadsheetURL = ss.getUrl(); // get the current active sheet url 
var SpreadsheetID = spreadsheetURL.split("/")[5]; // using the last / for getting the last parts of the email
var filterViewName = 'PO_Log Precentage'; // Name of the filter view you want to get the url from & MAKE SURE Title matches view name account for "spaces" too
var filterViewID = filterId(SpreadsheetID, filterViewName); // Getting filter view id 
var url = createURL(spreadsheetURL, filterViewID); // creating the url to send the filter view id
Logger.log(url);// Testing to see the correct url is created 
var po_numID = ss.getSheetByName("Purchase Orders List").getRange("A2").getDisplayValue().substr(0,3);// Gets the Purchase Order List Sheet and the PO# the first 3 Characters of the PO in A2
Logger.log(po_numID);
var email_va = ss.getSheetByName("Purchase Orders List");

//gonna build statuses to look for into array
var statusesToEmail = ['On-going', '']

//"Status" is in Column T (Col 2)
//"Precent" is in Column Q  (Col 3)

var data = email_va.getDataRange().getValues()
//  //var headerRowNumber = 1; // When checking for emails in the sheet you want to exclude the header/title row 

var emailDataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17G0QohHxjuAcZzwRtQ6AUW3aMTEvLnmTPs_USGcwvDA/edit#gid=1242890521").getSheetByName("TestA"); // Get The URL from another spreadsheet based on URL

Logger.log(emailDataSheet.getSheetName());


 var emailData = emailDataSheet.getRange("A2:A").getDisplayValues().flat().map(po => po.substr(0,3));
    Logger.log(emailData)///Working to get the first 3 charcters in column A

    var subject = po_numID + " Po Log Daily Notification "; // Unique PoTitle of the email 
    
    
    var options = {} // Using the html body for the email 
  
    options.htmlBody = "Hi All, " + "The following" + '<a href=\"' +url+ '" > Purchase Orders </a>' + "are over 90% spent" + "";

   for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      let row = data[i];
      if( statusesToEmail.includes(row[1]) & (row[2] >= .80)){
     emailData.every((po, index) => {
    if (po == po_numID){
      const email = emailDataSheet.getRange(index + 2,7).getValue();//Getting the last colmun on the same row when the Po# are the same.
      console.log(email);
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, '', options); // Sending the email which includes the url in options and sending it to the email address after making sure the first 3 Charcters Of the PO_log are the same as 
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });
  }
}

}
```

here is the spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QW5PIGzy_NSh4MT3j_7PggxXq4XcW4dCKr4wKqIAp0E/edit#gid=611584429

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use the break function if u wish to stop the loop once the loop has been fulfiled, because if im not wrong , the email is sent if the IF condition is met , thus in the block that has mailapp.sendemail , you have to add in a break otherwise the loop will keep on happening. this is the basic of javascript and you should read up more about the **FOR** loop [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

break as in just type "break" at the end of the code so the script will not continue to loop once the condition has been met.